# Formatting the search input of a jQuery Mobile Filtered List

Tags: list, jquery-mobile, filter, formatting

I have implemented a filtered list in jQuery Mobile using this [example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-search.html). It seems implementing a filterable list is as simple as using the following attributes in a  tag:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
```

When the code is compiled jQuery Mobile automatically adds an input field at the top of the list with terrific filter functionality. The problem I'm having is that because the search input is created on the fly I'm not sure how to format it. For example I'd like to have it up in the header with data-position="fixed" along with some other buttons. Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this.

Comment: If you right click and inspect element, maybe you can see the class name or field type. Then write some css that targets that.  Put it below the jquery mobile css.

Comment: duplicated with 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681799/jquery-mobile-data-filter-fixed-position-static